# What is the difference between clicking a checkbox and calling its '.click()' function?

Tags: html, jquery

Consider [the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/YfJTF/):

HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' />
<div>Click here</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').click(function() {
        document.write($(this).is(':checked') ? "checked" : "unckecked");
    });
    $('div').click(function() {
        $('input').click();
    });
});
```

When the checkbox is clicked, the output is `checked`, but if "Click here" is clicked the output is `unckecked`. Why is that?

Comment: I realize you are probably just giving an example here but on the off chance that you want something like this to work you should use the label tag instead. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YfJTF/1/)

Comment: @Tom - That's not correct, `this` always refers to the input, you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c8Ucr/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the `click` event is different from the `change` event, which is where the element changes.  When the `<div>` does a `.click()` is triggers the `click` event which hasn't yet changed the state of the checkbox so when it checks it, it's in the previous state.

When you click *directly* on the `<input>`, you've already changed the state, even if the `change` event fires 2nd in order, the main point is the checkboxes `checked` status has changed, *before* the `click` handler is checking for it, so the state is current.

If you want accurate state information look for and trigger the `change` event instead,  like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        $("span").append("<br />" + (this.checked ? "Checked" : "Uncecked"));
    });
    $('div').click(function() {
        $('input').click().change();
    });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c8Ucr/), on the off-chance this isn't a behavior question and you're wanting an external clickable area, [this is how I'd do it](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c8Ucr/2/) (via a `<label>` wrapping the input).
    ​

Comment: you're probably right.  I misunderstood because instead of fixing his broken demo, I just answered the question how I interpreted it :-P +1.

Comment: @Misha - Welcome, @Andy - Thanks :) I think yours is a good addendum to the question for others finding it, looking for that route...undelete it and you'd get a +1 from me at least.